# How to make Wine look for DLL in Program Files instead of /usr/share?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wine, games, .net

I'm trying to run a game called [Beneath the Nexus](https://playbtn.com/) through Wine. The game said I needed .NET Desktop Runtime 5, so I downloaded the [Windows installer](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) and installed it. However when running the actual game, I get the following error message:

> Message: A fatal error occurred, the required library hostfxr.dll could not be found in [Z:\usr\share\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.7]

when I run `find . | grep hostfxr` in my `.wine` prefix, it finds the right DLL in a few places:

```
./drive_c/Program Files/dotnet/host/fxr/5.0.7/hostfxr.dll
./drive_c/Program Files (x86)/dotnet/host/fxr/5.0.7/hostfxr.dll
```

How can I make the game find these DLLs instead of looking in my `/usr/share`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the installer working by copying the DLL into the location of the .exe. Not sure why I had to do that, but it worked:

```
cd ./path/to/game
cp ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/dotnet/host/fxr/5.0.7/hostfxr.dll .
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is an older post, but after 6 hours I've found a solution that's actually annoyingly simple.

When you run Wine through the terminal, all you need to do is add 'DOTNET_ROOT=' and put the Windows path to wherever your dotnet is installed.(By default it is: C:\Program Files\dotnet)

This is how the full command should look:

```
WINEPREFIX=/PATH/TO/PREFIX DOTNET_ROOT="C:\Program Files\dotnet" wine foo.exe
```

Hope this helps someone!